# Failed to update Linux headers on debian stretch / Debian 9

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, linux-headers

After running below command i got error:

```
# apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-4.9.0-3-amd64
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-4.9.0-3-amd64'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-4.9.0-3-amd64'
```

To troubleshoot i checked following:

````
# apt-cache search linux-headers
aufs-dkms - DKMS files to build and install aufs
linux-libc-dev-arm64-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-armel-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-armhf-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-mips-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-mips64el-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-mipsel-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-ppc64el-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-s390x-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-alpha-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-hppa-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-m68k-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-mips64-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-powerpc-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-powerpcspe-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-ppc64-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-sh4-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-sparc64-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-headers-4.9.0-11-all - All header files for Linux 4.9 (meta-package)
linux-headers-4.9.0-11-all-amd64 - All header files for Linux 4.9 (meta-package)
linux-headers-4.9.0-11-amd64 - Header files for Linux 4.9.0-11-amd64
linux-headers-4.9.0-11-common - Common header files for Linux 4.9.0-11
linux-headers-4.9.0-11-common-rt - Common header files for Linux 4.9.0-11-rt
linux-headers-4.9.0-11-rt-amd64 - Header files for Linux 4.9.0-11-rt-amd64
linux-headers-amd64 - Header files for Linux amd64 configuration (meta-package)
linux-headers-rt-amd64 - Header files for Linux rt-amd64 configuration (meta-package)```


and 

# apt-cache search linux-image
linux-headers-4.9.0-11-amd64 - Header files for Linux 4.9.0-11-amd64
linux-headers-4.9.0-11-rt-amd64 - Header files for Linux 4.9.0-11-rt-amd64
linux-image-4.9.0-11-amd64 - Linux 4.9 for 64-bit PCs
linux-image-4.9.0-11-amd64-dbg - Debug symbols for linux-image-4.9.0-11-amd64
linux-image-4.9.0-11-rt-amd64 - Linux 4.9 for 64-bit PCs, PREEMPT_RT
linux-image-4.9.0-11-rt-amd64-dbg - Debug symbols for linux-image-4.9.0-11-rt-amd64
linux-image-amd64 - Linux for 64-bit PCs (meta-package)
linux-image-amd64-dbg - Debugging symbols for Linux amd64 configuration (meta-package)
linux-image-rt-amd64 - Linux for 64-bit PCs (meta-package), PREEMPT_RT
linux-image-rt-amd64-dbg - Debugging symbols for Linux rt-amd64 configuration (meta-package)
linux-image-4.9.0-3-amd64 - Linux 4.9 for 64-bit PCs
````

After running  **apt-cache search linux-image** i get **linux-image-4.9.0-3-amd64** kernal version which i want in the result of **apt-cache search linux-headers** command also.

Few people suggested to change sources.list and then try. But as i am new to this i don't have idea how to search proper link for sources.list and what will be best suited to resolve my problem.

I did search on google but did not find solution. Any link or solution which can provide solution will be of great help.

Comment: Tried in another machine. Getting same error:

# apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package linux-headers-4.9.0-8-amd64 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

**E: Package 'linux-headers-4.9.0-8-amd64' has no installation candidate**

Comment: You should update your system first , `apt update && apt upgrade` , reboot then `apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

Comment: @GAD3R: Thank you for answering. I used your approach and finally i found the kernal upgraded to **4.9.0-11-amd64**. This output i got after running uname -r command.  I don't want to upgrade the kernal. i want the kernal to be **4.9.0-3-amd64**. Please suggest how to do this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For

```
apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

to work, you need to be *running* a kernel which is still available from the distribution repositories; in most cases, this basically means you need to be running the latest supported kernel for your distribution.

On Debian, the simplest option is

```
apt-get update
apt-get install linux-image-amd64 linux-headers-amd64
```

(adjust to your architecture) to get the current kernel and matching headers, then reboot.

Comment: Getting below error. Don't know the reason. Please help:
# apt-get install linux-image-amd64 linux-headers-amd64
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. 
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-headers-amd64 : Depends: linux-headers-4.9.0-8-amd64 but it is not installable
 linux-image-amd64 : Depends: linux-image-4.9.0-8-amd64 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: I missed a step, you need `apt-get update` first.

Comment: I tried your solution this also worked for me. But i wanted to know if some how i can user same old kernal and its corresponding headers. Also i wanted to know if doing so have some drawbacks. If yes then what are those and why? You can also refer some link from where i can learn about all these concepts. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: See [GAD3R’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/543631/86440) if you really want to use an older kernel. However there are quite a few drawbacks: older kernels have more known security issues... I highly recommend keeping up-to-date with distribution kernel releases. See [Greg KH’s talk on the kernel release model at Kernel Recipes 2017](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/543631/86440) and [his blog post on which stable kernel to use](http://www.kroah.com/log/blog/2018/08/24/what-stable-kernel-should-i-use/).

Answer (score 10):

The `linux-headers-4.9.0-3-amd64` is outdated , it is removed and replaced with the more recent package [`linux-headers-4.9.0-11-amd64`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/linux-headers-amd64) that's why you can't install it from the regular repository.

You can install the [`linux-headers-4.9.0-3-amd64`](https://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20170609T034604Z/pool/main/l/linux/) from the [snapshot archive repository](https://snapshot.debian.org/):

edit your sources list:

```
nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/snapshot.list
```

Add the following lines:

```
deb http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20170609T034604Z stretch main
deb http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20170609T034604Z stretch-updates main
deb http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian-security/20170920T221221Z stretch/updates main
```

then:

```
apt -o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false update
apt install linux-headers-4.9.0-3-amd64
```

> To access snapshots of suites using Valid-Until that are older than a dozen days, it is necessary to ignore the Valid-Until header within Release files, in order to prevent apt from disregarding snapshot entries ("Release file expired"). Use `aptitude -o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false update` or `apt-get -o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false` update for this purpose.

Comment: Thank you. This is what i need. I will try this solution and update soon.

Comment: I ran into this same issue. I'm using the Vagrant boxes published by Debian themselves for Puppet acceptance tests and both Stretch and Buster now can't find the linux-headers package that matches the kernel version installed in each Vagrant box. I don't have the ability (or desire) to be able to patch and reboot the box as part of the test process, plus the machines by definition aren't long-lived anyway. I figured Debian wouldn't delete the packages and that they're there somewhere in a source so thanks for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me after I submitted the command: `apt-cache search linux-headers`. I chose `linux-headers-5.4.0-1009-oracle` from the list. I'm using Windows 10 Professional!

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-5.4.0-1009-oracle
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-oracle-headers-5.4.0-1009
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-5.4.0-1009-oracle linux-oracle-headers-5.4.0-1009
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 21 not upgraded.
Need to get 12.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 87.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 linux-oracle-headers-5.4.0-1009 all 5.4.0-1009.9 [11.0 MB]Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 linux-headers-5.4.0-1009-oracle amd64 5.4.0-1009.9 [1244 kB]
Fetched 12.2 MB in 1min 12s (170 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package linux-oracle-headers-5.4.0-1009.
(Reading database ... 99989 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-oracle-headers-5.4.0-1009_5.4.0-1009.9_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-oracle-headers-5.4.0-1009 (5.4.0-1009.9) ...

Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-5.4.0-1009-oracle.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-5.4.0-1009-oracle_5.4.0-1009.9_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-5.4.0-1009-oracle (5.4.0-1009.9) ...
Setting up linux-oracle-headers-5.4.0-1009 (5.4.0-1009.9) ...
Setting up linux-headers-5.4.0-1009-oracle (5.4.0-1009.9) ...
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.4.0-1009-oracle

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
make -j8 KERNELRELEASE=5.4.0-1009-oracle -C /lib/modules/5.4.0-1009-oracle/build M=/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build................
cleaning build area...

DKMS: build completed.

vboxdrv.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.4.0-1009-oracle/updates/dkms/

vboxnetadp.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.4.0-1009-oracle/updates/dkms/

vboxnetflt.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.4.0-1009-oracle/updates/dkms/

depmod...

DKMS: install completed.
   ...done.
```